# Get length of Textbox before and after delimiter?

Tags: c#, textbox, delimiter, string-length

I have a textbox that will always have a delimiter in between two words such as Houston|Texas

How do I get the length of the text before, and the length of the text after the '|' delimiter into two separate integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string strTest = "Houston|Texas";
string[] strArr = strTest.Split('|');

int intFirst = strArr[0].Length; //Will result to 7
int intSecond = strArr[1].Length; //Will result to 5
```

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick for you

```
string ajks = "Houston|Texas";
List<int> LengthList = ajks.Split('|').Select(x => x.Length).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use one of this function I like to compare with:

```
string last = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('|') + 1);
string first = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('|') - 1);
```

//added

```
int last = (str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('|') + 1)).Length;
int first = (str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('|') - 1)).Length;
```